# How to extract Cookie Data from Request Body in Jmeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter, performance-testing

I have to extract cookie data from request body of a HTTP Request. Please guide me how can i achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not passed in request body.

- From server to browser they come in [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header
- From browser to server they go in [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header

See [Using HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) article for more details.

In JMeter there is a special test element - [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager). It automatically extracts cookies from the server response, stores them internally and if domain and path of the next request match - the cookie(s) are added to the Cookie header of the next request.

In case you want to access the values of cookies which are stored in the HTTP Cookie Manager anywhere else - you can add `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` property to *user.properties* file and upon JMeter restart cookies will be saved into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) with `COOKIE_` prefix